# Facebook android SDK for eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, sdk

i'm trying to make a simple android app which will have a login with facebook button and sharing stuff to facebook.
So i googled this ALOT but cannot find anything that will help me build this in eclipse.
Not in ANDROID STUDIO.
Every sdk tha i've found is for android studio, every tutorial is for android studio.
Is it now even possible to do this in eclipse? and if yes then please help.
Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer this links
[Sharing on fb](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

[login with fb](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

Comment: these links are not helpful as i can't even get the SDK for eclipse

Answer (score 2):

eclipse does not use gradle as android studio and other 'modern' IDEs do.
To use a libary in eclipse you need to download a *.jar or *.aar file.
I recommend you to use Android Studio because I don't see any advantages in eclipse. Android Studio is the new standard and it is worth it to learn how to use it.
Happy coding!

Comment: i know android studio is new and better but actually i work in an organization where we use eclipse only so i can't do it in android studio

Comment: @raviraghav I know what you mean :D
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android
You could check this link. At least there is a download button. I don't know if this is the right one but if not you could try to search for 'android Facebook sdk aar'.
Good luck

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. this link is just the same as previous one's